# Ant java task NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: ant

I want to make a simple ant build hibernate test project.
There is no error during the compilation and the build (jar).

But when I run it I get this:

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration ...
```

I have found an advise, what said : jars should be added to classpath in the command line, (classpath is ignored when the jar run from ant ... ehh), ok I tried the following:

```
 java -jar dist/student.jar -cp /home/myname/workspace/basic_ant1/lib/hibernate/hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar
```

But still have the some error :NoClassDefFoundError ...

What did I wrong ?

Thanks for the replies in advance.

(org.hibernate.cfg is in hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar)

Cs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant gets stuck while building runnable jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644414/ant-gets-stuck-while-building-runnable-jar)

Comment: Mark, thats title you mention is too abstract.

Comment: Agreed, but the solution is not. This question is repeatedly asked  under different guises. NoClassDef exceptions when running the jar. Exactly same root cause, a failure to populate the "Class-Path" portion of the manifest file. I hope my example helped.

Comment: Mark, sorry, I thought that you have to warn me from Stackoverflow because I could find it. I got you, sorry and many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-jar` and `-cp` are mutually exclusive.

If you want to use `java -jar` then your main JAR file needs a `Class-Path` entry in its manifest that points to all the other jars its `Main-Class` requires (the `manifestclasspath` task is a handy way to generate this value).

If you use `java -cp` then you have to give the main class name on the command line, the `Main-Class` from the manifest is ignored.

Comment: Many thanks Ian, thanks to mention 'manifestclasspath' because I read a similar solution before, but I cant believe that I should list all the dependent jar into to manifest manually (when I have already have a well defined classpath for the compile). Thats why I ignored that solution. Really thanks